# Add a contact to a group using Zend_GData and Google Contacts API

Tags: php, contacts, zend-gdata

I have an application using zend_gdata and create contact with the code below.

```
$doc  = new DOMDocument();
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$entry = $doc->createElement('atom:entry');
$entry->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/' ,'xmlns:atom', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
$entry->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/' , 'xmlns:gd', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');
$doc->appendChild($entry);

// add name element
$name = $doc->createElement('gd:name');
$entry->appendChild($name);

$fullName = $doc->createElement('gd:fullName', htmlentities($data->firstname . ' ' . $data->lastname));
$name->appendChild($fullName);

// insert entry
$entryResult = $gdata->insertEntry($doc->saveXML(), 'http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full');
```

Is there a possibility, a function to add a group to the contact just created?

Comment: what do you mean by "add a group to the contact"? Is it "add the contact to a group"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a big class and can't paste it all, you need to put this together somehow

step 1)

get all groups ( http://raiyaraj.wordpress.com/2008/09/17/gmail-gdata-contacts-group-via-proxy/)  and find the id of your group or create it ( you can do it with zend framework) if it doesn't exist

step 2)

generate the xml

```
// create new entry
        $doc  = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->formatOutput = true;
        $entry = $doc->createElement('atom:entry');
        $entry->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/' , 'xmlns:atom', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
        $entry->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/' , 'xmlns:gd', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');
        $entry->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/' , 'xmlns:gContact', 'http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008');
        $doc->appendChild($entry);

...add various stuff....
    $name = $doc->createElement('gd:name');
            $entry->appendChild($name);
            $fullName = $doc->createElement('gd:fullName', $this->name);
            $name->appendChild($fullName);
.....

        $group = $doc->createElement('gContact:groupMembershipInfo');
        $group->setAttribute('deleted' ,'false');
        $group->setAttribute('href' ,'http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/' .urlencode($this->email) . '/base/'.$this->group_id);
        $entry->appendChild($group);
```

step 3)

connect to gmail and execute the query

```
$service = $this->service;
// perform login and set protocol version to 3.0
$client = $service;
$gdata = new Zend_Gdata($client);
$gdata->setMajorProtocolVersion(3);
$entryResult = $gdata->insertEntry($this->getXML(), 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full');

return $entryResult->getLink('edit');
```

notice that you return the edit link so that if you save it, you can update the contact or or check for modifications

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Refer the following documentation for the same.

http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/reference.html#groupMembershipInfo

Comment: @max4ever can you post your source code(or sample code), so it **will** be helpful to others?